# How to increase the row height in sub-grid

Tags: forms, dynamics-crm, subgrid

I have a unique requirement where I need to display all the contents of an attribute in a sub-grid. This attribute stores multiple line of text i.e. a few paragraphs of text. The maximum column length of 300px is not enough to display such text without cutting off.

Is there a way I can increase the row height in sub-grids so that long text warps into multiple lines?

Answer (score 3):

No I don't believe this is possible. The row height is fixed.